# extjs, expand all children as a treePanel

Tags: tree, extjs4

expand all children as a tree.panel, I've used:

nametreepanel.expandAll ();

but I only open the first level, I want to open all levels of tree.panel

greetings and thanks ....

Comment: Post your code, please.

Answer (score 4):

You can recursively expand all the children of a given node with node.expand([recursive]).

[Documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface-method-expand)

Example: 
nametreepanel.getRootNode().expand(true);

Answer (score 0):

The expandAll() method of TreePanel is just enough. This method depends of your way to load the tree, if you load the tree on a only request or if you load the tree by levels. So, presumably there are a bug in your code and would be better if you post it.